# how to handle multiple submit buttons in spring mvc in java. One Submit buttons is for Server side and another is only for Client Side

Tags: spring

I am trying to handle multiple submit buttons in spring mvc in java. 1st Submit buttons is for Server side call and 2nd Submit button is  only for Client Side call.

But here the problem here I am facing is, for both submit button, control is going to Server side . I am Using plane jsp with spring tag. Here my requirement is one submit button should work for server side & another submit button only works for client side.

CODE Snippet:

```
<body>
<div>
<form:form commandName="route" method="post" action="routeSave" id="route">
<div class="center">

Start:<form:input  path="start" id="start" maxlength="50"/>
End:<form:input  path="end" id="end" maxlength="50"/>
City:<form:input  path="city" id="city" maxlength="50" onchange="mapcenter()"/>
RouteName:<form:input  path="routeName" id="routeName" maxlength="50"/>
StartTime:<form:input path="startTime" id="startTime" maxlength="50"/>

<form:button value="SaveMap">Save Button</form:button>

<form:button value="SaveMap" onclick="save_map()">Save Map</form:button>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with spring, you should check javascript function and ajax  call to send data to server side.

Answer (score 1):

A button of type="button" will not submit a form to a URL. A button of type="submit" (the default) will. So use a type="button" button for the client side action.

```
<form:form>

    <button type="button" name="btn1">no submit</button>

    <button type="submit" name="btn2">submit</button>

</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with for Example jQuery:

```
$( "#route" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The event Element has additional Information to handle it in handler-Method. See jQuery Docs.